# What is the fastest way to combine 100 CSV files with headers into one?

Tags: python, r, csv

What is the fastest way to combine 100 CSV files with headers into one with the following setup:

1. The total size of files is 200 MB. (The size is reduced to make the
   computation time visible)
2. The files are located on an SSD with a maximum speed of 240 MB/s.
3. The CPU has 4 cores so multi-threading and multiple processes are
   allowed.
4. There exists only one node (important for Spark)
5. The available memory is 15 GB. So the files easily fit into memory.
6. The OS is Linux (Debian Jessie)
7. The computer is actually a n1-standard-4 instance in Google Cloud.

(The detailed setup was included to make the scope of the question more specific. The changes were made according to [the feedback here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349793/why-is-benchmarking-a-specific-task-in-multiple-languages-considered-too-broad))

File 1.csv:

```
a,b
1,2
```

File 2.csv:

```
a,b
3,4
```

Final out.csv:

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```

According to my benchmarks the fastest from all the proposed methods is pure python. Is there any faster method?

**Benchmarks (Updated with the methods from comments and posts):**

```
Method                      Time
pure python                  0.298s
sed                          1.9s
awk                          2.5s
R data.table                 4.4s
R data.table with colClasses 4.4s
Spark 2                     40.2s
python pandas          1min 11.0s
```

Versions of tools:

```
sed 4.2.2
awk: mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996
Python 3.6.1
Pandas 0.20.1
R 3.4.0
data.table 1.10.4
Spark 2.1.1
```

**Code in Jupyter notebooks:**

sed:

```
%%time
!head temp/in/1.csv > temp/merged_sed.csv
!sed 1d temp/in/*.csv >> temp/merged_sed.csv
```

Pure Python all binary read-write with undocumented behavior of "next":

```
%%time
with open("temp/merged_pure_python2.csv","wb") as fout:
    # first file:
    with open("temp/in/1.csv", "rb") as f:
        fout.write(f.read())
    # now the rest:    
    for num in range(2,101):
        with open("temp/in/"+str(num)+".csv", "rb") as f:
            next(f) # skip the header
            fout.write(f.read())
```

awk:

```
%%time
!awk 'NR==1; FNR==1{{next}} 1' temp/in/*.csv > temp/merged_awk.csv
```

R data.table:

```
%%time
%%R
filenames <- paste0("temp/in/",list.files(path="temp/in/",pattern="*.csv"))
files <- lapply(filenames, fread)
merged_data <- rbindlist(files, use.names=F)
fwrite(merged_data, file="temp/merged_R_fwrite.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

R data.table with colClasses:

```
%%time
%%R
filenames <- paste0("temp/in/",list.files(path="temp/in/",pattern="*.csv"))
files <- lapply(filenames, fread,colClasses=c(
    V1="integer",
    V2="integer",
    V3="integer",
    V4="integer",
    V5="integer",
    V6="integer",
    V7="integer",
    V8="integer",
    V9="integer",
    V10="integer"))
merged_data <- rbindlist(files, use.names=F)
fwrite(merged_data, file="temp/merged_R_fwrite.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Spark (pyspark):

```
%%time
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("temp/in/*.csv")
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv("temp/merged_pyspark.csv")
```

Python pandas:

```
%%time
import pandas as pd

interesting_files = glob.glob("temp/in/*.csv")
df_list = []
for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
full_df = pd.concat(df_list)

full_df.to_csv("temp/merged_pandas.csv", index=False)
```

Data was generated by:

```
%%R
df=data.table(replicate(10,sample(0:9,100000,rep=TRUE)))
for (i in 1:100){
    write.csv(df,paste0("temp/in/",i,".csv"), row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: How large are the files? And did you use Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Try `fout.write(f.read())` instead of the loops, and try opening the files as binary files (with `"wb"` for writing and `"rb"` for reading). How long does it take then?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll be notably different than Spark, but Apache Drill (even run locally) is really good at this sort of thing.

Comment: In Python 3.x. you should open the csv files with `open(<filename>, mode='<read or write>', newline='')`.

Comment: @keiv.fly Exactly like you're doing it already.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I get an error on `next(f)` if I open the output file as binary

Comment: @keiv.fly That makes no sense, as `next(f)` works on the input file and shouldn't have anything to do with the output file. Are you sure you did it correctly? Also, what error?

Comment: @keiv.fly Looks like one of your files is empty.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I corrected the data and it is now below 1 second. You can make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @keiv.fly Why are you still reading the files as text files and encoding before writing? Instead of just reading as binary like I suggested.

Comment: With R data.table, providing the column classes should be faster... Can't see it beating the pure python benchmark though

Comment: Do you include the writing part in the timings. You could improve the write part with fwrite from data.table.

Comment: @StefanPochmann That was because the behavior of next() is not documented for binary files. I changed the code to all binary - it is now 0.3 seconds.

Comment: @AkhilNair after using `fwrite`, using `colClasses=c(V1="integer",...)` did not improve the speed

Comment: @Hugh I changed to fwrite and it is now 4.4s. Pretty impressive.

Comment: You may get even faster speed if you leave fwrite in append mode during lapply.

Comment: @keiv.fly sorry I meant pass the colclasses in the fread so they don't have to be guessed. Passing them in the write should make 0 difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too simplistic and likely as much to do with I/O subsystem performance as much as any specific tool's relative merits.

Comment: @MarkSetchell According to my benchmarks the difference is huge and is not I/O bound. Currently Python outperforms sed 10 times. It should be the same if you were right.

Comment: @keiv.fly Where did you see next() documented for *text* files? I'd like to have a look at that. [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) sounds like the difference is just encoding and line endings and [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) talks about iterating line by line and doesn't distinguish binary and text files for this. Anyway, you could also do something like `data = f.read(); fout.write(data[data.index(b'\n') + 1:])`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Can you post your binary python solution as an answer?

Comment: @keiv.fly Same as what you have now. Feel free to post it as an answer yourself if you want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the benchmarks in the question the fastest method is pure Python with undocumented "next()" function behavior with binary files. The method was proposed by [Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann)

Benchmarks:

**Benchmarks (Updated with the methods from comments and posts):**

```
Method                      Time
pure python                  0.298s
sed                          1.9s
awk                          2.5s
R data.table                 4.4s
R data.table with colClasses 4.4s
Spark 2                     40.2s
python pandas          1min 11.0s
```

Versions of tools:

```
sed 4.2.2
awk: mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996
Python 3.6.1
Pandas 0.20.1
R 3.4.0
data.table 1.10.4
Spark 2.1.1
```

Pure Python code:

```
with open("temp/merged_pure_python2.csv","wb") as fout:
    # first file:
    with open("temp/in/1.csv", "rb") as f:
        fout.write(f.read())
    # now the rest:    
    for num in range(2,101):
        with open("temp/in/"+str(num)+".csv", "rb") as f:
            next(f) # skip the header
            fout.write(f.read())
```

Comment: the pure python solution (very nice btw!) gives me the following error: `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`. I've fixed it by skipping the `next(f)` and using just `fout.write("".join(f.readlines()[1:]))`

Comment: @Gombo I never had this problem. What version of Python do you use? I used the code a week ago with Python 3.7 and it worked without errors. Using readlines should slow the execution, because python needs to find `\n` and fill a new list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is probably the fastest.  I would also propose an `awk` alternative

```
awk 'NR==1; FNR==1{next} 1' file* > output
```

prints the first line from the first file, then skips all other first lines from the rest of the files.

Timings:
I tried 10,000 lines long 100 files each around <strike>200MB</strike> (not sure).  Here is a worst timing on my server.

```
real    0m0.429s                                              
user    0m0.360s                                      
sys     0m0.068s
```

server specs (little monster)

```
$ lscpu                                                                                                         
Architecture:          x86_64                                                                                                             
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit                                                                                                     
Byte Order:            Little Endian                                                                                                      
CPU(s):                12                                                                                                                 
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11                                                                                                               
Thread(s) per core:    1                                                                                                                  
Core(s) per socket:    6                                                                                                                  
Socket(s):             2                                                                                                                  
NUMA node(s):          1                                                                                                                  
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel                                                                                                       
CPU family:            6                                                                                                                  
Model:                 63                                                                                                                 
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz                                                                          
Stepping:              2                                                                                                                  
CPU MHz:               2394.345                                                                                                           
BogoMIPS:              4789.86                                                                                                            
Virtualization:        VT-x                                                                                                               
L1d cache:             32K                                                                                                                
L1i cache:             32K                                                                                                                
L2 cache:              256K                                                                                                               
L3 cache:              15360K                                                                                                             
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-11
```

Comment: `sed` isn't even the fastest in their tests. Are you talking about a different way to use `sed`?

Comment: No, sorry, didn't see the timings.  Pleasantly surprised that Python is *faster*.  My guess is `awk` will beat it.

Comment: Hopefully they'll include your solution in the benchmark. But Python should be even faster than it currently is, as currently there's decoding plus encoding for as far as I can tell no reason, instead of just raw reading and writing.

Comment: Your server can read and write and process 20GB in less than 0.5 seconds? What kind of monster is that?

Comment: Doesn't look like a monster. I don't think your files are anywhere near 200MB each. Or something else is wrong. Btw, the OPs files are 200MB **total** (I just ran their creation code, each file is 2MB, 100000 lines with 20 bytes each).

Comment: I added awk to the benchmarks. It is a bit slower than sed. And it is old. The version on my Debian Jessie is from 1996.