# Combine multiple CSV files with Same Header into different group files

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv, awk

Hi I am looking for a fastest solution to process loads of csv files.

*Situation:*
**I have multiple csv files in a single folder with *different* headers**

I have already done pre-processing on them to remove garbage lines on top so all has a *Standard Header*.

I would like to *MERGE GROUP OF CSV FILES* with *EXACT SAME HEARERS* to a *New folder*

```
Single Folder:
    Tree 
    ├── 161598827330618_data_aa.csv 
    ├── ..............  
    ├── ............... 
    ├── ................ 
    ├── 161598852706227_data_bh.csv 
Note: Filenames are Random with no pattern*
```

Sample File-1.csv

```
School Name,Project Description,Construction Award,Project type,Building ID,Building Address,City,Postcode
George HS - QUEENS,New,76850000,CAP,Q298,50-51 98TH STREET,Queens,11368 
MARBLE HILL INTERNATIONAL HS -,EXT MASONRY/FLOOD/PARAPETS/ROOFS,10490000,CIP,X475,99 TERRACE VIEW AVENUE,Bronx,10463
NEW DORP HS - STATEN ISLAND,PARTIAL ACCESSIBILITY,488000,CIP,R435,465 NEW DORP LANE,Staten Island,10306
```

Sample File-2.csv

```
School Name,Project Description,Construction Award,Project type,Building ID,Building Address,City,Postcode
EAST SIDE COMMUNITY SCHOOL,FIFTH FLOOR CEILING REPLACEMENT,150000,CIP,M060,420 EAST 12 STREET,Manhattan,10009
RICHMOND HILL HS - QUEENS,STEEL DETERIORATED COLUMS & COLUMN,1064400,CIP,Q475,89-30 114 STREET,Queens,11418
SUCCESS ACADEMY CHARTER SCHOOL,INTERIOR STAIRS,2045000,CIP,M099,410 EAST 100 STREET,Manhattan,10029
```

Sample File-3.csv

```
Reporting Period,Project Number,City,County,Zip Code,Sector,Solicitation,Electric Utility
02/28/2021,2453,Youngstown,,14174,Non-Residential,ARRA Projects,National Grid
02/28/2021,218852,Queens,Queens,11356,Residential,PON 2112,Consolidated Edison
02/28/2021,220037,Warwick,Orange,10990,Residential,PON 2112,Orange and Rockland Utilities
02/28/2021,2011-230103-SLPR,Center Moriches,Suffolk,11934,Residential,Solar ARRA Funding,Long Island Power Authority
```

Sample File-4.csv

```
Reporting Period,Project Number,City,County,Zip Code,Sector,Solicitation,Electric Utility
02/28/2021,2453,Youngstown,,14174,Non-Residential,ARRA Projects,National Grid
02/28/2021,218852,Queens,Queens,11356,Residential,PON 2112,Consolidated Edison
02/28/2021,220037,Warwick,Orange,10990,Residential,PON 2112,Orange and Rockland Utilities
02/28/2021,2011-230103-SLPR,Center Moriches,Suffolk,11934,Residential,Solar ARRA Funding,Long Island Power Authority
```

Sample File-5.csv

```
OBJECTID,Borough,PSSite,ParkName,ParkZone,PSStatus,GlobalID,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate
283721,Brooklyn,Street,,,Populated,C90AAD08-D99E-4759-A64C-219D6143BFB3,07-08-15 13:10,12/20/2019 04:34:58 PM
7669836,Queens,Park,Astoria Park,Q004-ZN02,Empty,AB55A658-8276-4734-A698-5FFCAE96578E,08/13/2020 01:18:00 PM,08/20/2020 06:15:32 PM
7123408,Brooklyn,Park,Asser Levy Park,,Populated,B32D93C9-5958-4129-A87A-FA7C9A5A4E87,01-09-20 13:15,01-09-20 13:17
```

Sample File-6.csv

```
OBJECTID,Borough,PSSite,ParkName,ParkZone,PSStatus,GlobalID,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate
6036681,Manhattan,Park,Riverside Park,,Populated,6A3E747D-CD5E-43EB-9789-67DB2064E878,04-11-18 11:11,08-06-20 21:21
7170578,Bronx,Park,Garden Of Eden,,Populated,B1E8B660-4B65-437F-B61F-06B1B71A4E1C,01/28/2020 03:18:00 PM,01/28/2020 03:19:26 PM
740416,Bronx,Park,Mullaly Park,X034-ZN02,Populated,E8F51E3B-CC6F-46A3-AF17-02B6BE8DCC57,08/26/2015 04:34:00 PM,01/30/2020 04:10:41 PM
5004669,Queens,Street,,,Populated,20157769-88EC-4867-9F50-852EF4814BF0,11-02-16 16:56,08-03-20 13:12:00 AM
```

Sample File-7.csv

```
Indicator,Group,State,Subgroup,Phase,Time Period,Time Period Label,Value,Low CI,High CI,Confidence Interval
Private Health Insurance Coverage,National Estimate,United States,United States,1,1,Apr 23 - May 5,75.4,74.7,76.2,74.7 - 76.2
Public Health Insurance Coverage,By Age,United States,18 - 24 years,1,1,Apr 23 - May 5,19.5,15.4,24.3,15.4 - 24.3
Uninsured at the Time of Interview,By Gender,United States,Female,1,1,Apr 23 - May 5,11,10.3,11.7,10.3 - 11.7
```

Sample File-8.csv

```
Year, dtmSurveyDate, ColonyID, strAOUCode, Type, strPhotoInterpreters, strColonyName, strCounty, strState, strCountry
2014,03-Jun-14,219-001,COMU,Image Check - No Birds,Kirsten Bixler,"""Tillamook Head Rocks"" (Eastern Rocks)",Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
2014,03-Jun-14,219-002,COMU,Image Check - No Birds,Kirsten Bixler,"""Tillamook Head Rocks"" (Northern Rock)",Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
2014,03-Jun-14,219-003,COMU,Shapefile-RawCount,Kirsten Bixler,"""Tillamook Head Rocks"" (Southwestern Rocks)",Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
2014,03-Jun-14,219-005,COMU,Shapefile,Shawn W. Stephensen,Tillamook Rock,Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
```

**Desired Result:**

Sample File-1.csv } 
Sample File-2.csv } Header check > `Same Header found`> MERGE  > `GROUP-1.csv`

Sample File-3.csv } 
Sample File-4.csv } Header check > `Same Header found`> MERGER > `GROUP-2.csv`

Sample File-5.csv }
Sample File-6.csv } Header check > `Same Header found` > MERGER > `GROUP-3.csv`

Sample File-7.csv } Header check > `No Similar Headers`  > NOTHING> `GROUP-5.csv`
Sample File-8.csv } Header check > `No Similar Headers`  > NOTHING> `GROUP-6.csv`

Preferable Solution: Bash Script and Linux Commands
Solutions Tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  FNR==1{
    if (!($0 in h)||file!=h[$0]){close(file)}
    if (!($0 in h)){file=h[$0]=i++}
    else{file=h[$0];next}
  }
  {print >> (file)}
' ./*.csv
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602291/459978

The above method work but I am not sure if it can handle 1000s of files for processing and categorizing.
I need Group*.csv formats to be created in an different folder.

Shortest Time of Completion is important
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921621/3088275

**Looking for an Op code with Awk or Sed or Linux commands for bash script which ever is fastest to achieve the desired output**

Comment: *"I am not sure if it can handle 1000s of files"* ... how has your testing performed? have you hit out-of-memory issues? is the process *'slow'* and if so, can you elaborate on what you mean by *'slow'*?

Comment: during your *'pre-processing'* did you by any chance collect all of your headers **plus** associated file names into a single file (eg, `header_1:file1\nheader_1:file2\nheader-7:file3:...`) ?  if so, you could sort said file (by header) and then via a simple `bash\while` loop (or `awk` if you prefer) process the rows from said file, using the 2nd field (filename) to directly perform a `cat/head <filename> >> <finalfile>`

Comment: @markp-fuso oops edited #7, #8 go into different groups `Group-5.csv` and `Group-6.csv` as the HEADERs doesnt match any of them in the folder

Comment: You have python in your tags, use that if you know how.  Much faster than any script solution you will come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following AWK script. I tested it with all the sample files.

```
!NF { next }
NR % 3 == 1 { filename = substr($0, 5, length($0)-8) }
NR % 3 == 2 { headers[$0] = headers[$0] (headers[$0] == "" ? "" : ",") filename }

END {
  i=1
  for (header in headers) {\
    printf("Group %02d: %s\n", i, headers[header])
    split(headers[header], a, ",")
    for (idx in a) {
      getline x < a[idx]
      printf "" > sprintf("group%02d.txt", i)
      while (getline x < a[idx] > 0)
        print x >> (sprintf("group%02d.txt", i))
    }
    i++
  }
}
```

```
$ ls Sample\ File-*
Sample File-1.csv Sample File-3.csv Sample File-5.csv Sample File-7.csv
Sample File-2.csv Sample File-4.csv Sample File-6.csv Sample File-8.csv
$ head -n 1 Sample\ File-* | awk -f script.awk
Group 01: Sample File-1.csv,Sample File-2.csv
Group 02: Sample File-8.csv
Group 03: Sample File-7.csv
Group 04: Sample File-5.csv,Sample File-6.csv
Group 05: Sample File-3.csv,Sample File-4.csv
$ cat group01.txt
George HS - QUEENS,New,76850000,CAP,Q298,50-51 98TH STREET,Queens,11368
MARBLE HILL INTERNATIONAL HS -,EXT MASONRY/FLOOD/PARAPETS/ROOFS,10490000,CIP,X475,99 TERRACE VIEW AVENUE,Bronx,10463
NEW DORP HS - STATEN ISLAND,PARTIAL ACCESSIBILITY,488000,CIP,R435,465 NEW DORP LANE,Staten Island,10306
EAST SIDE COMMUNITY SCHOOL,FIFTH FLOOR CEILING REPLACEMENT,150000,CIP,M060,420 EAST 12 STREET,Manhattan,10009
RICHMOND HILL HS - QUEENS,STEEL DETERIORATED COLUMS & COLUMN,1064400,CIP,Q475,89-30 114 STREET,Queens,11418
SUCCESS ACADEMY CHARTER SCHOOL,INTERIOR STAIRS,2045000,CIP,M099,410 EAST 100 STREET,Manhattan,10029
$ cat group02.txt
02/28/2021,2453,Youngstown,,14174,Non-Residential,ARRA Projects,National Grid
02/28/2021,218852,Queens,Queens,11356,Residential,PON 2112,Consolidated Edison
02/28/2021,220037,Warwick,Orange,10990,Residential,PON 2112,Orange and Rockland Utilities
02/28/2021,2011-230103-SLPR,Center Moriches,Suffolk,11934,Residential,Solar ARRA Funding,Long Island Power Authority
```